# Are there any known/researched bifurcations where time is the control parameter?

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems, bifurcation

Bifurcations are usually determined compared to some external parameter $\lambda$  that can be independently controlled. But what if we take time to be our parameter, that is, the system experiences a bifurcation simply with the passage of time? Is there any research/literature on this?

Comment: The phenomenom called "hysteresis" has some similarity to this scenario. The parameter in $y'(t)=f(y(t),r(t))$ depends on time as $r(t)=A\cos(t)$ or a similarly periodic function, and the DE $y'(t)=f(y(t),r)$ for fixed parameter has fold points or other bifurcations that force a change of the stable equilibrium branch in the range $r\in[-A,A]$. // The vander Pol oscillator $x'=\mu(v-F(x))$, $v'=-x/\mu$ has a similar behavior in an autonomous dynamic, with $v$ as the slow moving bifurcation parameter.

Comment: This area is called *dynamic bifurcation theory* and it's an active research area, including applications. For an overview look at the proceedings of the Luminy workshop of 1990 (published by Springer), and further work quoting it. One of the most striking phenomena is a *delay effect*, where e.g. a solution may stay near an equilibrium for a finite time after it has lost its stability in a Hopf  bifurcation.

Comment: @HansEngler Thank you, I'll start there.

Comment: There is also a notion of [*rate-induced* bifurcations](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2111.15497.pdf), when non-autonomous part of equation includes frequency explicitly.